# In a jframe, can I choose what component is selected on start up?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

For example, can I have a certain JTextField be selected and ready to type in when the program starts? How do I do this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please show us what you've tried so far

Comment: have you tried requestFocus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `requestFocusInWindow()` on the component you wish to have focus. However, this statement must be executed AFTER the GUI is visible:

```
frame.add(....);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
textField.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Or another approach is to add an `AncestorListener` to the component and have the component request focus on itself whenever the component is displayed on a visible GUI. Check out the `Request Focus Listener` found in [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/).